# Negative divergence implies convergent flow?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics

Suppose we have a differentiable vector field $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R^n}$ defined on an open, bounded and simply connected region subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$, and its divergence is negative everywhere, i.e. $\nabla\cdot X(x)<0$ for any $x\in\Omega$. Can we prove that any two solution trajectories will evolve closer and closer, and thus eventually convergent?

Formally, given any two points $p,q\in\Omega$ and flows $p(t), q(t)$ satisfying $p(0)=p,q(0)=q,\dot p(t)=X(p(t)), \dot q(t)=X(q(t))$, define $f(t)=||p(t)-q(t)||^2$, then is it true that
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)<0$$

Intuitively, I think it is right because negative divergence implies any closed area will evolve smaller and smaller. So if we enclose two points with a thin tube, then the volume of this tube will get smaller and smaller, which forces points get closer.

Here is my try:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=2\left<p-q|X(p)-X(q)\right>=2\left<p-q|\nabla X(r)|p-q\right>$$
The first equation follows from the definition and the second from mean value theorem(though this theorem doesn't exist). But this seems the statement requires more rigid condition, say positiveness of $\nabla X$, to guarantee the corectness.

Comment: I think that some additional assumptions are needed, because $x' = x, y' = -2y$ seems to perfectly satisfy your conditions, but it's dissipative saddle and not all points converge to the same trajectory. Since it is possible to have dissipative saddle, the effect will persist even if you have closed invariant domain.

Comment: The "classical" [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) has constant negative divergence, but the flow is chaotic. (The domain is unbounded, but I believe that's not an essential feature.) One serious problem with the proposed argument is that a volume estimate gives no information about diameter.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang As far as I remember, for classic parameter values of Lorenz system there is a trapping region. So everything is pretty OK with your example :)

Comment: @Evgeny: Thank you; I had a vague recollection that one orbit escaped, but on closer re-inspection couldn't reproduce the reasons I might have thought this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g$ be a smooth, non-negative function (not identically zero) with support contained in some interval $[0, R^{2}]$. The vector field
$$
X(x, y, z) = g(x^{2} + y^{2})(-y, x, 0) + (0, 0, kz)
$$
defined on the open cylinder
$$
\Omega = \{(x, y, z) : x^{2} + y^{2} < R^{2},\ |z| < 1\},
$$
is complete (the flow exists for all positive time) and has divergence $-k$, but a pair of orbits do not approach each other pointwise in any reasonable sense. Indeed, the flow can be written explicitly: If $r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2}$, then
$$
\Phi_{t}(x, y, z)
  = \left(x\cos\bigl(g(r^{2})t\bigr) - y\sin\bigl(g(r^{2})t\bigr),
          y\cos\bigl(g(r^{2})t\bigr) + x\sin\bigl(g(r^{2})t\bigr),
          ze^{-kt}\right).
$$
Geometrically, a point $(x, y, z)$ at distance $r$ from the $z$-axis travels in a circle around the $z$-axis by a distance of $rg(r^{2})$ per unit time (and the aggregate motion is incompressible in the "horizontal" directions) while the third component decays exponentially to $0$.